# OUTER APPLY não funciona como o INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sei que o comando OUTER APPLY é analogo ao INNER JOIN, mas estou confuso com uma situação onde isto não acontece.

A consulta abaixo extraída do Training Kit 70-461:

```
SELECT c.custid 
FROM Sales.MyCustomers AS C
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) O.shippostalcode
                FROM Sales.MyOrders AS O 
                WHERE O.custid = C.custid
                ORDER BY orderdate, orderid) as A;
```

89 linhas são retornadas.

Mas ao realizar a consulta:

```
SELECT * from Sales.MyCustomers C
INNER JOIN Sales.MyOrders O
ON c.custid = o.custid
```

830 linhas são retornadas.

A consulta interna retorna apenas uma linha devido ao TOP:

```
SELECT TOP (1) O.shippostalcode
Sales.MyOrders AS O, Sales.MyCustomers C 
WHERE O.custid = C.custid
ORDER BY orderdate, orderid
```

Por qual motivo o CROSS APPLY retorna 89 linhas? E o INNER JOIN 830? Se a consulta interna retorna apenas 1 linha este não seria o único valor a ser comparado?

Comment: No primeiro caso, vc faz um SELECT que limita o numero de dados e depois um CROSS APPLY usando o resultado do SELECT, quando, no segunda caso, vc faz somente um INNER JOIN. Entao, parece logico que no primeira caso, vc tem menos resultado que no segundo. Tenta fazer somente o CROSS APPLY no primeiro caso, sem o sub-SELECT para ver o resultado.
Um dethale: na sua pergunta vc fala de OUTER APPLY. De verdade, acho que OUTER APPLY = LEFT OUTER JOIN e CROSS APPLY = INNER JOIN.

Comment: Queria me referir ao CROSS APPLY, mas acabei trocando os nomes.@Peter muito obrigado  pela ajuda! Continuei testando por aqui e acabei simulando o mesmo resultado com o INNER JOIN selecionando somente os id's e fazendo um DISTINCT na seguinte forma:                                       SELECT DISTINCT c.custid, d.custid from Sales.MyCustomers AS C 
inner join Sales.MyOrders AS D
ON C.custid = D.custid
Na primeira consulta o uso do TOP na consulta a direita funcionaria como um DISTINCT limitando a combinação a apenas uma linha?

Comment: TOP() serve para limitar o numero de dados que vc vai receber. Colocando um TOP(1) significa que vc vai receber somente um resultado cada vez. Como vc faz O.custid = C.custid, se vc tem somente 89 diferentes C.custid, vc vai receber somente 89 resultados depois do SELECT. Então neste caso, acho que o TOP() vai ter o mesmo efeito que o DISTINCT do segundo query. A pergunta e saber se 89 e o resultado que vc espera (e neste caso precisa deixar o TOP o fazer o DISTINCT) o se 830 e o bom resultado. Testa sem o TOP() para ver.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos, pode efetuar as correções editando a sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

Apena para reforçar o que o Peter já te respondeu, o CROSS APPLY é bem diferente do INNER JOIN.

Falando em termos simples, o INNER JOIN é uma operação matemática, um produto cartesiano das informações entre a Tabela A e a tabela B nas operações. As condições de limitação e filtro do conjunto selecionado ocorre em uma segunda etapa, no WHERE (embora o JOIN já limite um pouco da informação, o produto cartesiano ainda está aplicado, trazendo toneladas de informações a mais).

Já o CROSS APPLY acontece em uma etapa superior para a tabela em que ocorre o CROSS APPLY. Assim podemos realizar um TOP ou trazer menos registros **ANTES** do produto cruzado realmente acontecer.

Em termos práticos, invés de realizar um JOIN (produto cartesiano) com a tabela original, o APPLY faz esse produto com o **RESULTADO** do que foi selecionado na tabela onde o APPLY está sendo feito. Isso significa também que em termos práticos, é muito mais rápido realizar um CROSS JOIN do que um INNER JOIN quando sabemos que há muitos dados que não vão ser exibidos em uma `query`, tendo em visto que o CROSS APPLY somente vai aplicar o produto cartesiano nas linhas que se *aplicam*, já o *JOIN* será em todas primeiro, depois serão filtradas.